# Как сделать ограниченное создание рандомных бомб?

Tags: c#, c++, winforms

Начал писать игру "Сапер", не могу решить проблему с ограниченным созданием бомб. Вообще программа работает, но как то коряво, потому что я обошел проблему созданием процентного соотношения. Но мне не нравится! И вот как эту проблему решить?

```
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        int width = 10;
        int height = 10;
        int offset = 30;
        int bombPercent = 30;
        FieldButton[,] field;
        public void Generater()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int x = 0; x < height; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
                {
                    FieldButton newButton = new FieldButton();
                    newButton.Location = new Point(x * offset, (y + 1) * offset);
                    newButton.Size = new Size(offset, offset);
                    if (random.Next(0, 100) <= bombPercent)
                    {
                        newButton.isBomb = true;
                    }
                    Controls.Add(newButton);
                    newButton.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(GGorWin);
                    field[x, y] = newButton;
                }
            }
        }
        public void GGorWin(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            FieldButton clickedButton = (FieldButton)sender;
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (clickedButton.isBomb)
                {
                    GG();
                }
                else
                {
                    LetsGO(clickedButton);
                }

            }
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                clickedButton.Text = "Ф";
            }
        }
        public void GG()
        {
            foreach (FieldButton button in field)
            {
                if (button.isBomb)
                {
                    button.Text = "*";
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Вы проиграли");
            Application.Restart();
        }
        void LetsGO(FieldButton clickedButton)
        {
            int bombsAround = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    if (field[x, y] == clickedButton)
                    {
                        bombsAround = BombsAround(x, y);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (bombsAround == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                clickedButton.Text = "" + bombsAround;
            }
            clickedButton.Enabled = false;
        }
        int BombsAround(int x1, int y1)
        {
            int bombsAround = 0;
            for (int x = x1 - 1; x <= x1 + 1; x++)
            {
                for (int y = y1 - 1; y <= y1 + 1; y++)
                {
                    if (x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height)
                    {
                        if (field[x, y].isBomb == true)
                        {
                            bombsAround++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return bombsAround;
        }

        private void новаяИграToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            field = new FieldButton[width, height];
            Generater();
        }
    }
    public class FieldButton : Button
    {
        public bool isBomb ;
    }
```

Comment: Неожиданно, само по себе решение понравилось. как я понял, автор вопроса, не мудрствуя лукаво, для каждого игрового поля создаёт стандартную "кнопку" (ну, наследника кнопки - FieldButton). Очнь ловко и остроумно, в стиле "я его слепила из того, что было" (ну, а что взять с WinForms, заточенных под бизнес - приложения?). И на самом деле - хорошо получилось! А в каком конкретно месте проблема возникает?

Comment: Проблема в методе Generater. Я хочу ограниченное количество бомб, собственно, как в реальной игре "Сапер"

Comment: Как бы Вы отнеслись к такому решению: заводим внешний "счетчик бомб", внутри двух вложенных циклов - считаем, если кол-во бомб стало "достатчоным" - выходим из цикла по break? Если Вас "идеологически" это устроит - я могуи и этот метод "изобразить"

Comment: @S.H Я думал об этом, но я не могу это подставить к random.Next( ) и Controls.Add(newButton) .Можете показать реализацию, как вы это видите?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На первый взгляд, хотелось бы написать простое исправление кода, типа такого:

```
    public void Generater(int bMax)  // здесь bMax - кол-во бомб, котрые надо сгенерировать
    {
    int bCounter=0;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int x = 0; x < height; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
        {
            FieldButton newButton = new FieldButton();
            newButton.Location = new Point(x * offset, (y + 1) * offset);
            newButton.Size = new Size(offset, offset);
            if (random.Next(0, 100) <= bombPercent)
            {
                newButton.isBomb = true;
                bCounter++; // здесь мы увеличили "счетчик бомб"
            }
            Controls.Add(newButton);
            newButton.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(GGorWin);
            field[x, y] = newButton;
            // а теперь можно проверить, не достигли ли мы необходимого кол-ва
            if (bCounter==bMax)
                break;

        }
        // эта проверка нужна по той причине, что break "выкидывает" нас наружу только одного цикла
        if (bCounter==bMax)
            break;
    }
```

Но самом деле у этого кода **есть две проблемы**: 1) он может не сгенерировать нужного кол-ва бомб. Оба цикла отработают, а bMax не будет достигнут. 2) при генерации нужного кол-ва бомб код заканчивает работу, не сгенериовав всё игровое поле!

Чтобы это исправить, хорошо бы поменять сам метод генерации бомб: сделать не цикл  по поординатам (и второй вложенный цикл по другим координатам), а цикл по кол-ву бомб, который генерирует их со случайными координатами.

Но у Вас в коде "совмещено" два процесса: генерация "кнопок" (которые нужно сгенерировать в любом случае, независимо от того, с бомбой кнопка или нет) и установка признака "эта кнопка - с бомбой"!

Поэтому я бы разделил функцию Generater() на две - генерации поля и генерации бомб.

я попробовал написать код "на коленке", и, заранее извиняюсь, еслив нём есть ошибки:

```
    private void новаяИграToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        field = new FieldButton[width, height];
        GenerateFields();
        GenerateBombs( bombPercent );
    }

    public void GenerateFields()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < height; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
            {
                FieldButton newButton = new FieldButton();
                newButton.Location = new Point(x * offset, (y + 1) * offset);
                newButton.Size = new Size(offset, offset);
                Controls.Add(newButton);
                newButton.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(GGorWin);
                field[x, y] = newButton;
            }
        }
    }

    public void GenerateBombs(int bombPercent) 
    {
        // нам передали процент полей, который должны быть заминированы. 
        // Сделаем из него абсолютное кол-во бомб:
        int bMax = width * height * bombPercent / 100;
        Random random = new Random();
        int bCounter=0;
        while ( bombPercent< bMax){
            // теперь гененрируем случайные координаты бомбы
            int randx = random.Next( 0, width );
            int randy = random.Next( 0, height );
            if ( !field[randx, randy].isBomb )
            {
                field[randx, randy].isBomb = true;
                bCounter++;   // увеличиваем кол-во сгенерированных бомб
            // проверка условия нужна для реализации принципа "две бомбы в одну воронку не падают": 
            // если поле уже "заминировано" - то его повторное минирование не увеличит счетчик
             }
        }

    }
```

Надеюсь, основную идею он доносит.

Где могут быть ошибки: например, я мог перепутать width и height

Еще по поводу кода: слелующим этапом может стать "причёсывание кода": например, не увлекайтесь глобальными переменными. Пробуйте передавать в функцию только то, что необходимо.

Ну, а потом можно взяться за разделенеи уровней "отображения" и "работы с данными" (разделение на View и Controller).

Comment: если разбить на 2 метода, то он вообще не генерирует бомбы :( Что довольно странно, очень логичный код, который не хочет работать

Comment: проверьте тот участок кода, который начинается с if ( !field[randx, randy].isBomb ) - я там сначала забыл сделать генерациюб бомб, а потом исправил. Возможно, Вы увидели предыдущую версию :-) Если не поможет - пишите, тогда открою "студию" и попробую воспроизвести ошибку

Comment: Мне не очень не удобно такое говорить, но он все равно не работает. Создает поле с кнопками - прожимая на них, не выводятся бомбы

Comment: Хм... ладно, сейчас загрузим код в "полноценную" студию и запустим!

Comment: получилось решить проблему.

Comment: Круто! А ошибка то была очень простой, кажется: я неправильно считал кол-во бомб, корые надо сгенерировать...

Answer (score 1):

Без помощи пользователя S.H - не получилось бы, огромное Спасибо!

```
public void GenerateBombs(int bombs)
        {
            int row, col;//индексы клетки
            int n = 0;//количество поставленных мин
            Random rnd = new Random();
            do
            {
                row = rnd.Next(0,width);
                col = rnd.Next(0,height);
                if (!field[row, col].isBomb)
                {
                    field[row, col].isBomb = true;
                    n++;
                }
            }
            while (n != bombs);//проверка как раз таки
        }
 private void новаяИграToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        field = new FieldButton[width, height];
        GenerateFields();
        GenerateBombs(bombs);
    }

    public void GenerateFields()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < height; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
            {
                FieldButton newButton = new FieldButton();
                newButton.Location = new Point(x * offset, (y + 1) * offset);
                newButton.Size = new Size(offset, offset);
                Controls.Add(newButton);
                newButton.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(GGorWin);
                field[x, y] = newButton;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]